# Edit Item in Sharepoint List with filter

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint, spservices

Can anyone help my on how to edit an item on a list with a where clause.
For example I want to set the Title = Besmonte where the currently title = Rey

I can edit an item in the list but is still using the ID of the entry.

please help.

```js
-- External Jquery
     $().SPServices({
                 operation :"UpdateListItems",
                 async: true,
                 webURL: this.spSiteUrl,
                 valuepairs:[["Title", "Rey"]],
                 listName: "SampleList",
                 ID:1   
      });
```

```html
-- SP library
   <script src="../javascript/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../javascript/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../javascript/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you will have to do this in two steps. First retrieving the items to be updated and then use your code to update the selected items using the ids retrieved

Comment: That's actually my approach right now. the problem with this is it would take time to load specially when we have thousand of entries. So I'm looking for a way to reduce the loading time.

Comment: have a look (google) at batch commands. I've seen it's also possible with SPServices but i'm unsure if you can have where conditions

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d4da24/update-sharepoint-list-items-using-spservices-and-batch/